# ARB Assembly to GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I have an NVidia example that uses an ARB Assembly shader:

```
!!ARBfp1.0
TEX result.color, fragment.texcoord, texture[0], RECT;
END
```

Now I would like to translate that into a GLSL shader. This is what I've come up with:

```
uniform sampler2D tex;

void main(void)
{
  vec4 col = texture2D ( tex, gl_TexCoord[0] );
  gl_FragColor = vec4(col.r, col.g, col.b, col.a);
}
```

I was hoping to see no change in the resulting rendering, but sadly I only get a black texture.

I've already made sure that the tex sampler is set correctly. Also my GLSL code compiles with no errors. For debugging I tried to make my shader even simpler:

```
void main(void)
{
  gl_FragColor = vec4(1,0,0,1);
}
```

This gives me a red texture. Thus my basic setup seems to be OK.

Comment: The texture is created correctly, since the assembler version works fine. The binding to the sampler also looks fine (checked all the IDs in the debugger). The tex coords should also be fine, since the drawing code is exactly the same for both shader variants (assembler and GLSL). Is there any way I can debug what's going on in the shader?

Comment: Yes, use RenderDoc. It lets you see shader inputs, texture, GL state, uniforms etc.

Comment: Hmm, you have a 2D texture but you are only passing one texture coord? Presumably t defaults to 0.0. And as noted below, an old RECT texture used integer coords from 0 to W/H, not float from 0 to 1. Check those values?

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the 4th parameter of `TEX`. It says `RECT`, so the sampler needs to have `sampler2DRect` type.

```
uniform sampler2DRect tex;

void main(void) {
  gl_FragColor = texture2DRect(tex, gl_TexCoord[0]);
}
```